# Implementing SQL "AND" search using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, frameworks, entity

I have the following SQL query -

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.LocalContacts WHERE name LIKE '%taiwan%' AND name LIKE '%mvp%'
```

How do I implement it using EF? I need to break down the search string, then do an 'AND' search for each of the keywords. I have the following but this is not what I wanted -

```
var searchTextLowerCase = Request.QueryString["q"].ToLower().Split(' ');
            foreach (var s in searchTextLowerCase)
            {
                foreach (var x in communities)
                {
                    if (
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name) && x.Name.ToLower().Contains(s)) ||
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Acronym) && x.Acronym.ToLower().Contains(s)) ||
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.OwnerFirstName) && x.OwnerFirstName.ToLower().Contains(s)) ||
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.OwnerEmail) && x.OwnerEmail.ToLower().Contains(s)) ||
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.OwnerLastName) && x.OwnerLastName.ToLower().Contains(s)) ||
                        )
                    {
                        if (!filteredCommunities.Exists(y => y.Id == x.Id))
                            filteredCommunities.Add(x);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can construct the SQL query on the fly and execute it against the DB, but can I do it using EF?

Comment: You can do this using LINQ when querying your Entity Framework data model. I'll try and put together an example shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work -

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  IQueryable<Product> query = dataContext.Products;

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    query = query.Where (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return query;
}
```

[Source](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this against a DB, though you should be able to create a Entity Framework model, and then query it. You can add more where conditions, to fullfill all your requirements:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string holder = "A B C D E";
    string[] searchTextLowerCase = holder.ToLower().Split(' ');

    using (Model1Container context = new Model1Container())
    {
        var q = context.Communities;
        List<Community> communities = q.Where(c => searchTextLowerCase.Contains(c.Name)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have to do a ToList() on the context.Communities call. I can't remember off the top of my head, though I don't think any of the Entity Framework database providers support a .Contains. This I think has to be performed on a generic list or such in memory, it's not supported on the call to the database.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure what you're doing with the .Split method, and looping through the multiple results of that. Though, if you know how many fields you need to query, and you only have one search string to query, you can simply put all of that within the Entity Framework linq call with a where clause, and you wouldn't need to use contains.

Comment: I tested your code snippet but I'm afraid it will not bring up any results. `  var allcontacts = db.LocalContacts.ToList();
            var filteredLocalContacts = allcontacts.Where(c => searchTextLowerCase.Contains(c.Name)).ToList();
            ucLocalContactsList.Bind(filteredLocalContacts);`

Comment: Nope, here's the code from Profiler - `SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
[Extent1].[LastModifiedOn] AS [LastModifiedOn], 
[Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes]
FROM [dbo].[LocalContacts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] IN (N'taiwan',N'mvp')`

Comment: Ok, so the query worked, though you need something with a Like %% rather than in(). This has some information: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it with `PredicateBuilder`:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Community>();
foreach(var s in searchTextLowerCase)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(s));
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Acronym.ToLower().Contains(s))
    //.. etc
}
var filteredCommunities = communities.Where(predicate);
```

The source for `PredicateBuilder`:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
    {
      public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
      public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

      public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                          Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
      {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
      }

      public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                           Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
      {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following message - The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. My code `            var allcontacts = db.LocalContacts;
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<LocalContact>();
            foreach (var s in searchTextLowerCase)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(s));
            }

            var filteredLocalContacts = allcontacts.Where(predicate);
            ucLocalContactsList.Bind(filteredLocalContacts.ToList());` grr.. why won't it format the code correctly?

Comment: That's right! I didn't recall this limitation of EF. `AsExpandable()` from LINQKit would get you past this.